# Accessing files in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am new to Google Colab. I have used the following code to download a data set from Kaggle:

```
!pip install kaggle

import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = "xxxxxxxxx"
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

!kaggle competitions download -c dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition

os.chdir('/content/')
#dowloaded data in this directory
```

I can access all the data now, but where is this data stored? In my Google Drive? But I can't find it. What if I want to access this same data from a different notebook running in Colab? Both notebooks are stored in my Google Drive, but seem to have their own different '/content/' folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to store the data in google drive you have to link the drive first using :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then you can access the drive by navigating through `"/content/drive/My Drive/"`

so you can download the data to your drive using the following command :

```
!kaggle competitions download -p "/content/drive/My Drive/" -c dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition
```